# Validate choice field DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Hi all I have my model and its serializer, what I discovered when testing is that serializer is saved no matter what I have in my choice field but in Django admin choice field is empty when the data is wrong and when the data is right I can see the correct option

so,

```
-> wrong choice data
-> saved regardless 
-> nothing in django admin
```

```
-> correct choice data
-> saved
-> correct value in django admin
```

How can I return validation error if I detect that user posted incorrect data?

what I was trying out is

```
topic = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=School.topic)
```

and I don't think that iterating over each tuple and searching for a string is correct or efficient

code

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = SchoolSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
class School(models.Model):

    SUBJECT = (
       ('Math', 'Mathematic'),
       ('Eng', 'English'),
       ('Cesolved', 'Chemistry'),
   )

    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(choices=SUBJECT, max_length=15, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.name} is {self.subject}')
```

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subject = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=School.SUBJECT)

    def validate(self, data):
        name = data["name"]
        if (5 > len(name)):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"IError": "Invalid name"})
 
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out version for checking if choice passed in the serializer is correct.

**Please let me know if there are better ways to do it**

Basically, I've imported my choice field from models into serializer and then converted it into dict and then in the validate function check if value exists

```
CHOICE_DICT = dict(School.SUBJECT)

def validate(self, data):

   choice = data["subject"]
   if not (choice in CHOICE_DICT):
      raise serializers.ValidationError({"Invalid Choice": f"Choice field is not valid. Valid choices {Contact.School}"})

        return data
```

I don't think that this is the fastest way to do this.